Can't save in Razor pages
I have a code to retrieve previously saved invoice data and a code to save it again after changing the price or quantity. The problem is that when I press the save button, nothing happens, no message appears, and the data is not saved.
using AfterFix.Pages.Clients;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AfterFix.Pages.Sales
{
    public class EditModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-9CABSPL\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mystore;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

        public SalesInfo salesInfo = new SalesInfo();
        public string errorMessage = "";
        public string SuccessMessage = "";
        public List<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; } = new List<InvoiceItem>();

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(int InvNo)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    await connection.OpenAsync();

                    string invoiceQuery = "SELECT id, ClientName, InvDate, InvNo, SubTotal FROM SalesInv WHERE InvNo = @InvNo;";
                    using (SqlCommand invoiceCommand = new SqlCommand(invoiceQuery, connection))
                    {
                        invoiceCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvNo", InvNo);
                        using (SqlDataReader invoiceReader = await invoiceCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                        {
                            if (invoiceReader.Read())
                            {
                                salesInfo.id = "" + invoiceReader.GetInt32(0);
                                salesInfo.ClientName = invoiceReader.GetString(1);
                                salesInfo.InvDate = invoiceReader.GetDateTime(2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                                salesInfo.InvNo = "" + invoiceReader.GetInt32(3);
                                salesInfo.SubTotal = invoiceReader.GetDecimal(4);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    string query = "SELECT ItemName, ItemQuantity, Price, InvNo FROM Titem WHERE InvNo = @InvNo";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvNo", InvNo);

                        using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                InvoiceItems.Add(new InvoiceItem
                                {
                                    ItemName = reader["ItemName"].ToString(),
                                    ItemQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ItemQuantity"]),
                                    Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Price"]),
                                    InvNo = Convert.ToInt32(reader["InvNo"])
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return Page();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
                return Page();
            }
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection innerConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    innerConnection.Open();

                    string itemSql = "INSERT INTO Titem (ItemName, ItemQuantity, Price) VALUES (@ItemName, @ItemQuantity, @Price);";

                    using (SqlCommand itemCommand = new SqlCommand(itemSql, innerConnection))
                    {
                        // Clear parameters once outside the loop
                        itemCommand.Parameters.Clear();

                        // Add parameters outside the loop (to be reused in each iteration)
                        itemCommand.Parameters.Add("@ItemName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                        itemCommand.Parameters.Add("@ItemQuantity", SqlDbType.Int);
                        itemCommand.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Decimal);

                        foreach (var item in InvoiceItems)
                        {
                            // Validate quantity and price format
                            if (!IsNumeric(item.ItemQuantity.ToString()) || !IsNumeric(item.Price.ToString()))
                            {
                                errorMessage = "Invalid quantity or price format.";
                                return Page();
                            }

                            // Set parameter values in each iteration
                            itemCommand.Parameters["@ItemName"].Value = item.ItemName;
                            itemCommand.Parameters["@ItemQuantity"].Value = item.ItemQuantity;
                            itemCommand.Parameters["@Price"].Value = item.Price;

                            itemCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }

                SuccessMessage = "تم حفظ البيانات بنجاح";
                return RedirectToPage("/Sales/Index");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}";
                return Page();
            }
        }


        // Helper method to validate numeric strings
        private bool IsNumeric(string value)
        {
            return decimal.TryParse(value, out _);
        }

        // Unrelated to error handling
        public class InvoiceItem
        {
            public string ItemName { get; set; }
            public int ItemQuantity { get; set; }
            public decimal Price { get; set; }
            public int InvNo { get; set; }
        }
    }
}


@page
@model AfterFix.Pages.Sales.EditModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit Invoice";
}

<h1>Edit Invoice</h1>

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.errorMessage))
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        @Model.errorMessage
    </div>
}

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SuccessMessage))
{
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        @Model.SuccessMessage
    </div>
}

<h2>Invoice Items</h2>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.InvoiceItems)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.ItemName</td>
                <td>@item.ItemQuantity</td>
                <td>@item.Price</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>


During the past four days, I changed everything and the code was limited to saving data only to find out the cause of the problem, but to no avail. The connection statement is fine and the code is as well. So what is the problem?

There's nothing inside your form but the submit button. If you want to send data to the backend, it needs to wrapped inside the form

In addition to what @RyanWilson said, the data needs to be in form fields, not table cells. Read about using forms in Razor Pages here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms

i changed the code like  but still can't save the data


The problem is that when I press the save button, nothing happens, no message appears, and the data is not saved.

You need to ensure InvoiceItems are properly bound on post handler and the SQL query is correct.
Ensure Model Binding
Firstly, there is nothing in your form so that it will post nothing to backend. Then model binding system binds the property by name attribute. So need post list model like below:
<form method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for(int i =0;i<Model.InvoiceItems.Count();i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><input asp-for="@Model.InvoiceItems[i].ItemName"/></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@Model.InvoiceItems[i].ItemQuantity" /></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@Model.InvoiceItems[i].Price" /></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>

At last you need use [BindProperty] helpers to ensure that the properties are properly bound to the form data when the form is submitted.
private readonly string _connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-9CABSPL\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mystore;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

public string errorMessage = "";
public string SuccessMessage = "";

[BindProperty]
public List<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; } = new List<InvoiceItem>();

Ensure SQL query
Be sure the SQL connection is correct and the table name Titem and column names ItemName, ItemQuantity, Price are correct.
